# Rearranging elements of an array based on properties of indexes

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I want to rearrange the elements of an integer array based on the number of factors of natural numbers.

So for example my array input would be [6, 16, 7] and output should be [7, 6, 16] because the factors of numbers are 4, 5, and 1. What would be the best way to solve it, I am thinking about two for loops, but am not fully sure, how to execute it. Here's, what I have done by now.

```js
var number;
var factors = 0;
var array = [];
while (number != 0) {
    number = +prompt("Input a natural number:");
    if (number != 0) {
        array.push(number);
    } else {
        break;
    }

}

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var a = numOfFactors(i);
    for () {
        if (numOfFactors(i) > numOfFactors(j)) {

        }
    }
}

function numOfFactors(a) {

    for (var i = a; i >= 1; --i) {
        if (a % i == 0 && i >> 0) {
            factors++;
        }
    }
    return factors;
}


numOfFactors(number);
console.log(factors);

console.log(array);
```

Thanks

I want to rearrange the array order with for loops if that would be possible

Comment: just `sort()` with a helper function to determine factor count.

Comment: isn't the number of factors of 7 is 2?